# Правила переноса слов с дефисом

Tags: перенос

Каковы современные правила переноса слов с дефисом типа «сине-зелёный»?

Я нашёл какой-то разнобой: одни не разрешают переносить по дефису, другие разрешают, третью рекомендуют именно по дефису, четвёртые требуют при этом повторения знака дефиса на следующей строке.

Можно ли переносить такие конструкции как «я-то»?

Comment: Конструкция «я-то» никак не переносится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правила **не запрещают** переносить слова в месте дефиса. 
Откуда взялись запреты или, наоборот, рекомендации переносить именно в месте дефиса, сказать сложно. В этой части никакой "факультативности" нет. Возможно, причина в том, что начиная с двадцатых годов прошлого века правила в этой части неоднократно менялись и изобретались доморощенные рекомендации.

Вот в отношении рекомендации **повторять дефис** (или знак переноса) на следующей строке - сложнее. Такое требование (не просто рекомендация) действительно существовало, если не ошибаюсь, еще в шестидесятых годах, при этом такой **вариант не считался предпочтительным** по сравнению с переносом в другом месте. Сейчас я уже давно не сталкивался с текстами, набранными с учетом подобного требования. Во всяком случае оно совершенно не актуально в случае, если дефис и знак переноса отличаются видом (хотя бы длиной).

Именно эту рекомендацию, повторять дефис на новой строке - и только её! -   справочник Лопатина (ссылку - см. Серж) и называет странным термином "факультативное правило", подразумевая "правило, которое применяется по желанию пишущего".

В остальном же правило, разрешающее перенос по дефису, совсем не факультативно (из ответа Сержа это понять сложно, см. первоисточник).

Answer (score 1):

Правило переноса слов через дефис является факультативным и применяется по желанию автора.

При переносе может потеряться различие между написаниями слов слитно и через дефис; ср.: военно-обязанный (пишется военнообязанный) и военно-морской (пишется военно-морской). **Для сохранения различия надо во втором случае повторить дефис в начале перенесенной части: военно- / -морской. Это правило применяется по желанию пишущего.**

См.: [Полный академический справочник под редакциеей Лопатина](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=97#pp97)