# Возможен ли разрыв переносом?

Tags: перенос

...75-летие
Возможен ли разрыв переносом? Вопрос касается текста.
...75-
летие

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ниже цитата из справочника А.Э. Мильчина.

> 8.3. СЛОЖНЫЕ СУЩЕСТВИТЕЛЬНЫЕ И ПРИЛАГАТЕЛЬНЫЕ С ЧИСЛИТЕЛЬНЫМИ В СОСТАВЕ
>
> 1. В изданиях художественной литературы такие существительные и прилагательные пишутся буквами. Например: стопятидесятилетие,
>    двадцатикилометровый переход.
> 2. В изданиях массовой не художественной литературы рекомендуется буквенно-цифровая форма (части присоединяются друг к другу дефисом).

О каких-либо запретах на перенос таких слов ничего не сказано. В этом случае действует правило: "что не запрещено, то разрешено". Более того, подобные слова в этом же параграфе перенесены между цифровой и буквенной частью.

Answer (score 1):

Предположу, что нестандартная эта ситуация не текстовая, а касается титула, плаката или иного индивидуального решения на листе. В таком случае обращение к правилам пунктуации и переноса не требуется: и чёрточку, и знак переноса по месту чёрточки ставить не следует. В тексте же перенос недопустим.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вопрос как раз по тексту.

Comment: В тексте всегда можно избежать цифр.

Comment: Но ведь можно перенести 75-ле-тия

Comment: Я ответил однозначно на конкретный вопрос с одним вариантом. Что до этого утверждения: кое-что, позволенное правилами, мешает чтению и не украшает строку и абзац, ибо несуразно

Answer (score 0):

Такой перенос возможен. Есть немало споров, о том, как не потерять различие между написаниями слов слитно и через дефис. Лопатин предлагает повторять дефис в начале перенесенной части ([ПРАВИЛА ПЕРЕНОСА (Факультативное правило)](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=97#pp97)). Другие источники запрещают это делать. На нашем сайте вопрос обсуждался здесь:
[Правила переноса слов с дефисом](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/433846/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BC).

Дополнение.
Нашел в Википедии:

> Кроме того, запрещено разрывать дефисные написания вроде «2-местный», «n-мерный», условные обозначения вроде «Боинг-767», телефонные номера, многозначные числа и др.

Но Википедия - не очень авторитетный источник.

Comment: Обсуждались, но не слова с числительными.

Comment: Источники авторитетные молчат, как здесь утверждают. И находка очень даже к месту: разрешать такие переносы умолчанием — неверно.